# Slow and Fast tokenizer gives different outputs(sentencepiece tokenization)

Tags: nlp, tokenize, huggingface-tokenizers, sentencepiece

When i use T5TokenizerFast(Tokenizer of T5 architecture), the output is expected as follows:

```
['▁', '</s>', '▁Hello', '▁', '<sep>', '</s>']
```

But when i use the normal tokenizer, it starts to split special token "/s>" as follows:

```
['▁</', 's', '>', '▁Hello', '<sep>', '</s>']
```

**And this is print of not fast tokenizer**:

```
PreTrainedTokenizer(name_or_path='', vocab_size=60000, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=False, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'pad_token': '<pad>'})
```

**For fast** :

```
PreTrainedTokenizerFast(name_or_path='', vocab_size=60000, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'pad_token': '<pad>'})
```

Code that i am using to produce these outputs:

```
tokenizer = T5TokenizerFast('new_sp.model', extra_ids=0)
tokenizer.add_tokens(['<sep>'])
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer.encode("</s> Hello <sep>")))
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you trained these tokenizers by yourself? I assume both were trained the same way? Can you share them?